# Image carrousel with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on a display for my images

I try to achieve something like this

[image]

I found on bootstrap documentation the Carrousel, it is close but not what I want to achieve.

How could I do this with bootstrap or another ressource without coding it in JS from scratch?

More precisely, how to do the carrousel (with multiple images) below the active image ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this website and select the one you want.
[bootstrap-4-carousel](https://colorlib.com/wp/bootstrap-4-carousel/)

There is one Carousel indicators with thumbnails which may fit your need.